# C# Key press (keyboard) to write a specific word by a string

Tags: c#, string, keyboard, keypress

I wanted to write a simple application, to get a word from a string, and keypress the keys corresponding of each letter from that string, to write that word, for example on notepad.

What I got so far is:

```
public void TestKeyboard()
{
    string a = "test"; //this is the string it should be written
    foreach (char c in a)
    {
        Keyboard.KeyPress(c); //how to obtain this? this isn't working
    }
}
```

How would you obtain the Keyboard.KeyPress event?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simulating Key Press c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047375/simulating-key-press-c-sharp)

Comment: @MathewHD it does not answer my question. What I wanted to do is read a word from a string and "type" that word letter by letter using keypress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void TestKeyboard()
{
    string a = "test";
    foreach (char c in a)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        SendKeys.Send(c.ToString());
    }

}
```

I hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you mean, you need to split the string you have into letters, and define the `Keyboard.KeyIsPressed(OfEachLetter)` and create an if statement to show the letter pressed. after using the KeyDown event.

[How do I split a word's letters into an Array in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246856/how-do-i-split-a-words-letters-into-an-array-in-c)
http://csharp.net-informations.com/gui/key-press-cs.htm http://csharp.net-informations.com/gui/key-press-cs.htm

P.S.: woosy programmer didn't have his coffee yet.
Cheers