# How can I parse HTTP urls in C#?

Tags: c#, parsing, url

My requirement is to parse Http Urls and call functions accordingly. In my current implementation, I am using nested if-else statement which i think is not an optimized way. Can you suggest some other efficient approch?

Urls are like these:

- `server/func1`
- `server/func1/SubFunc1`
- `server/func1/SubFunc2`
- `server/func2/SubFunc1`
- `server/func2/SubFunc2`

Comment: What about split the url's and get only the last token, if you only need the function names?

Comment: Can you be clearer on what you mean by "parse"?  I assume there's some specific data you want to extract; but what part and for which purpose?

Comment: There are many kind of urls which I get. It contains attributes, useful value in uris also.

Comment: Is it something like this you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70405/does-c-sharp-have-a-string-tokenizer-like-javas ? You can split the url's in the '/' and go through each token.

Comment: But again I have to use nested if else statements...

Comment: There are alternatives to nested if/else. `switch` comes to mind, as does using a table lookup. But without more information about what you're doing, it'll be impossible to give you any kind of recommendation.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I think you can get a lot of use out of the [System.Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.URI%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) class. Feed it a URI and you can pull out pieces in a number of arrangements.

Some examples:

```
Uri myUri = new Uri("http://server:8080/func2/SubFunc2?query=somevalue");

// Get host part (host name or address and port). Returns "server:8080".
string hostpart = myUri.Authority;

// Get path and query string parts. Returns "/func2/SubFunc2?query=somevalue".
string pathpart = myUri.PathAndQuery;

// Get path components. Trailing separators. Returns { "/", "func2/", "sunFunc2" }.
string[] pathsegments = myUri.Segments;

// Get query string. Returns "?query=somevalue".
string querystring = myUri.Query;
```

Answer (score 7):

This might come as a bit of a late answer but I found myself recently trying to parse some URLs and I went along using a combination of `Uri` and `System.Web.HttpUtility` as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29434651/1145114), my URLs were like `http://one-domain.com/some/segments/{param1}?param2=x....` so this is what I did:

```
var uri = new Uri(myUrl);
string param1 = uri.Segments.Last();

var parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
string param2 = parameters["param2"];
```

note that in both cases you'll be working with `string`s, and be specially weary when working with segments.

Answer (score 0):

I combined the  split in Suncat2000's answer with string splitting to get at interesting features of the URL. I am passing in a full Uri including https: etc. from another page as the navigation argument e.Parameter:

```
Uri playlistUri = (Uri)e.Parameter;
string youtubePlaylistUnParsed = playlistUri.Query;
char delimiterChar = '=';
string[] sections = youtubePlaylistUnParsed.Split(delimiterChar);
string YoutubePlaylist = sections[1];
```

This gets me the playlist in the PLs__ etc. form for use in the Google APIs.