# Elegant way parsing URL

Tags: c#, parsing

After POST/GET request I get such URL back which I need to parse, of course I can go and use spit() to get required information, but for sure should be more elegant way of doing that. Any ideas?

`http://api.vkontakte.ru/blank.html#access_token=8860213c0a392ba0971fb35bdfb0z605d459a9dcf9d2208ab60e714c3367681c6d091aa12a3fdd31a4872&expires_in=86400&user_id=34558123`

I am parsing for: `access token` and `expires_in`

Comment: Uri class ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get url parameters from a string in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659887/get-url-parameters-from-a-string-in-net)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Using the [URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class you can do this:

```
var url = new Uri("your url");
```

Comment: hm.. I looked in at URI class but not able to figure out how do I pars parameters using it. any examples?

Comment: uri.Query.Split('&') should give you all the query string parameters, when you can do a split by "=" to separate the value from the name.

Comment: You didn't answer his question, he wanted `access_token` and `expires_in`

Comment: `Uri.Query` holds the query parameters alone. `Uri.PathAndQuery` separates the path and query parameters by a `?`. And obviously `Uri.Path` holds the path if you want those to be separate variables.

Comment: Also you can use `Uri.TryCreate` to more gracefully handle the case where the supplied string is not a valid Uri.

Comment: This can only be used when validating absolute URLs. For relative ones, it allows plenty of values I wouldn't consider valid, for example `*`.

Answer (score 58):

Use Uri + ParseQueryString functions:

```
Uri myUri = new Uri("http://api.vkontakte.ru/blank.html#access_token=8860213c0a392ba0971fb35bdfb0z605d459a9dcf9d2208ab60e714c3367681c6d091aa12a3fdd31a4872&expires_in=86400&user_id=34558123");

String access_token = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("access_token");
String expires_in = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("expires_in");
```

This will also do the trick

```
String access_token = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get(0);
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx

Tip: You might need

```
using System.Web;
```

And add a reference to System.Web

Answer (score 19):

There are several ways you can do this. One is that you can simply use the [`Uri.Query`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.query(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get the query string and then parse by the &s. Another is that you can use the [`Uri.Query`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.query(v=vs.110).aspx) method and then use [`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx) to parse the query string as a [`NameValueCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection(v=vs.110).aspx), which might be your preferred route.

**See the example below:**

```
using System.Web; // For HttpUtility

// The original URL:
Uri unparsedUrl = new Uri("http://api.vkontakte.ru/blank.html#access_token=8860213c0a392ba0971fb35bdfb0z605d459a9dcf9d2208ab60e714c3367681c6d091aa12a3fdd31a4872&expires_in=86400&user_id=34558123");
// Grabs the query string from the URL:
string query = unparsedUrl.Query; 
// Parses the query string as a NameValueCollection:
var queryParams = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query);
```

You can now perform operations similar to how you would deal with a `Dictionary` object. Like so:

```
string accessToken = queryParams["access_token"];
string expiresIn = queryParams["expires_in"];
```

This has the same functionality as what @Jeroen Bouman showed, but splits apart the different functions so you can understand what each piece does individually.

**References:**

[Uri.Query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.query(v=vs.110).aspx)

[HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx)

[NameValueCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

this is late to the party, but since .NET 6, there is

```
 Uri.TryCreate (string? uriString, UriKind uriKind, out Uri? result);
```

Which should help with parsing without exception.

More on [MS Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.trycreate?view=net-7.0&devlangs=csharp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Uri.TryCreate)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue)