# Regex to extract domain from a url

Tags: c#, regex

I want to extract the domain name from the url. For example for `www.Edmunds.com/Toyota_Camry_Hybrid` or `http://jido.com` I want to have `www.Edmunds.com` and `jido.com`

I have written the following regular expression:

```
Regex.Replace(Url, @"^([a-zA-Z]+:\/\/)?([^\/]+)\/.*?$", "$2");
```

It works fine for the first link but for the second link I get: `http:`

Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713542/elegant-way-parsing-url

Comment: It is not a duplicate since, OP is clearly asking for a regular expression for extracting domain name from the url, not for an _"elegant way for parsing url"_. Fact, that the highest pointed answer is the same as in the linked question is irrelevant here, because it does not answer the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) class to get specific parts of a URL.

```
var uri = new Uri("www.Edmunds.com/Toyota_Camry_Hybrid");
Console.WriteLine(uri.Host);
```

Comment: You didn't answer the question. OP is clearly asking for a regular expression for extracting a domain name from url.

Comment: If you take a very pedantic view of the question then no, I didn't, but looking at the context of what OP was asking, then yes I did answer it - they weren't specifically looking to solve it via Regex, but just wanted a way to get the host.  I think the fact that OP marked this as answered probably validates that assumption.  I do appreciate though if you got here via Google then this answer isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, you guessed correctly. I came across three or so similar questions, all basically suggesting using `Uri`. I eventually found the wanted regular expression, but it honestly required spending quite some time searching.

Comment: And yet, unfortunately, you didn't see it fit to help people in your position by providing a link to the answer, or the regex itself

Answer (score 0):

```
(?=http*).*\/(.*)|(.*?)\/
```

You can try this. See [**demo**](http://regex101.com/r/sK8mL8/1).