# Dot Net RegExp to match specific URL with query string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to make a redirect tool for a website and I need a dotnet regular expression for an specific route with an specific query string.

I need to match 
/folder/file.aspx?options=all

I need to match the url part (/folder/file.aspx) as it is and in the query string match if the options=all parameter is there even if there are other parameters.

Comment: Are you trying to find matching URL within a page, or do you have a URL and are trying to check if it matches the rule?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using RegEx for this there is a dedicated [URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class in C# that will do this for you as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713542/elegant-way-parsing-url). You can combine it with [HttpUtitility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx) to extract the query parameters.

```
var uri = new Uri("/folder/file.aspx?options=all");
var options = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("options");
```

If you prefer Regex for non-obvious reasons, there you go:

```
var regex = new Regex("/folder/file\.aspx\?(?:\w+(?:=\w+)?&)*options=all");
```

You can see it live in action [on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bW2aV9/1).