# Get string between 2 known string by Regex

Tags: c#

I 'm having a link like this

```
href="abc.com/Details/gotoTicket?ticketID=EO8"
```

I want get an ID beetwen `gotoTicket?ticketID=` and `"`.

The result of link above I want is `EO8`

How can I do that with Regex ?

Comment: have you read this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 and sure you are not trying to parse html, and that this is a specific limited domain problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Elegant way parsing URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713542/elegant-way-parsing-url)

Comment: that final quote isn't actually in the string, you know.  You don't need to code for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need regex for that. You can use the `HttpUtility` to get your query string, e.g.

```cs
var href = new Uri("http://example.org/Details/gotoTicket?ticketID=EO8");
string ticketId = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(href.Query).Get("ticketID");
```

Just make sure that your `href` (URL) starts with a scheme.