# How to divide url path into segments?

Tags: c#

For instance, I have `[https]://localhost:7171/en-gb/main-page/parent-page`. I wanted to divide this url into segments like:

```
return fullPath?.Substring(0, fullPath.LastIndexOf('/'));
```

However, there can be cases such as `[https]://localhost:7171/en-gb/main-page/parent-page/pre-parent-page...../pre-pre-pre-pre-page`.

So, I decided to somehow divide it into several parts and write the segments into array/list/dictionary.

```
var segments = url?.Split('/', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Skip(2).ToArray();
```

And then need to find the path to its naming that will be initialized into Dictionary:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> SegmentsList = new()
{
    ["en-gb"] = "Culture",
    ["main-page"] = "Bookings",
    ["parent-page"] = "Adventures"
    ...
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't do this manually, there are many tools that are built for this, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713542/elegant-way-parsing-url)

Comment: This question is specifically asking about the URL path. The "[Elegant way parsing URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713542/elegant-way-parsing-url)" is concerned with a URL fragment and "[Get URL parameters from a string in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659887/get-url-parameters-from-a-string-in-net)" is concerned with a URL QueryString

Comment: Construct a [`Uri` class instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=net-8.0) and use the [`Segments` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.segments?view=net-8.0) to get an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code uses the [`Uri` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=net-8.0) to parse the URL and retrieve the segments of the path using the [`Segments` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.segments?view=net-8.0).

```cs
var uri = new Uri("https://localhost:7171/en-gb/main-page/parent-page");
var segments = uri.Segments.Skip(1).Select(s => s.TrimEnd('/')).ToArray();
```

For the URL `https://localhost:7171/en-gb/main-page/parent-page`, the path segments are:

- /
- en-gb/
- main-page/
- parent-page

The `Skip(1)` is stepping over the initial `/` segment and the `Select()` is trimming ending `/` characters.