# How to get string from formatted url in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, url, c#-4.0, formatted

Suppose We are on the page `www.abc.com/apple-store`

then how to get string `apple-store` in asp C# code.

to store into another variable.

Comment: What means "we are on the page"? Is it your page?

Comment: @Tim

Yes    suppose  example.com/apple-store

i want to get this string  'apple-store'

and store into variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string.last() to extract it.

```
string lastPartUrl =HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Split('/').Last();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried lot but did not able to do it.
Your solution works!! great..

God bless you.

Comment: Glad i could assist you :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `Request.RawUrl` property. See more details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.rawurl(v=vs.110).aspx).

Alternatelly you can also use the `Request.Url` (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url(v=vs.110).aspx)) property to get different parts of the current URL. For example you will get the same result using `Request.Url.LocalPath`.

Comment: And then parse that as per this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685147/how-can-i-parse-http-urls-in-c

Comment: @ SmartDev

What is 'sw' . in link you have given mentioned this. i can't figure it.

sw.WriteLine(Server.HtmlEncode(Request.RawUrl));


The following code example uses the HtmlEncode method to HTML-encode the value of the RawUrl property and the WriteLine method to write the encoded value to the file. This code example is part of a larger example provided for the HttpRequest class.

Comment: `sw` it's a `StreamWriter`. The example uses it to write the result in a file. You don't need this. Just use `string url = Request.RawUrl;`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the url in a string variable. Further you can implement the below logic which will save the value in a variable.

```
string str = "www.abc.com/apple-store";
string result = "";
int i= 0;
int len = str.Length;

//Get the index of the character
i = str.IndexOf('/');    
//store the result in the variable
result = str.Substring(i+1,len-i-1);

Console.WriteLine("Resultant:- {0}", result);`
```

Hope this helps a bit.