# Regex to remove filepath from url C# .NET

Tags: c#, regex

I wrote this regex :

http://regexr.com/3cbis

Its job is to capture a web address but remove the filepath. 
e.g. www.example.com/removethis/andthis/  - leaving me with just www.example.com

The .NET tester I used (regexstorm.net/tester) gave me a different [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6USiX.png).

How would I fix my regex to give my desired result?

Comment: Don't do it with a regex. Do a `var url = new Uri(someAdress)`, then parse the domain name out it through `url.Host`. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14212007/5296568)

Comment: You can just split the string with `/` and use the 0th element.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a regex, use the `Uri` class which has built in `Host` property to extract the relevant part of the url.

Answer (score -1):

Use the URI class

See this stack overflow for an example

[How can I parse HTTP urls in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685147/how-can-i-parse-http-urls-in-c)