# Get last digits of url

Tags: c#, asp.net, httprequest, query-string

I get my url using Uri like this:

```
Uri requestUri = Context.Request.Url;
```

and my url is something like this

```
http://localhost:1597/Pages/BSC/pe_Rep.aspx?BSCID=27
```

I want to get only last part of url, I want toi get only digits after sign `=` so I want to get only value `27` I try to do it using Replace like:

```
var BSCID = requestUri.Replace("http://localhost:1597/Pages/BSC/pe_Rep.aspx?BSCID=", "");
```

But is like I can´t use url with Replace, can anyone help me how can I achieve this please?

Comment: Please, try using search before asking question. Here is an answer you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685147/how-can-i-parse-http-urls-in-c

Comment: @Rafa, a bit of reading that might help you here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string and https://www.dotnetperls.com/querystring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String replacement is the wrong way to go about this.

Use the `Context.Request.QueryString` dictionary to get the value of BSCID.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Context.Request.QueryString["BSCID"]))
{
    var BSCID = Context.Request.QueryString["BSCID"];
}
```

Comment: I try it but it just return me value 0

Comment: What do you get if you examine `Context.Request.QueryString.ToString()`?

Comment: I review it again and it works. thanks