# How to split a string using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am using a string to store country code with its cost centre code value . I want to spilit it out the string using LINQ query by  | and ; characters. The srting is

```
IND|001;TWN|002;USA|003;LDN|;MYS|005;
```

Please help me to spilt out the string value using LINQ

Comment: Is linq is necessary and what would be output?

Comment: Why not use String.Split?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70405/does-c-sharp-have-a-string-tokenizer-like-javas

Comment: I'd rather parse this input string using a state-machine, it would be a lot faster and consume less memory.

Comment: Without LINQ, you can use `String.Split()` method like `String.Split(new char[] {'|', ';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: String.Split is more than enough for simple cases. Regex can cover most advanced cases. LINQ should be used to handle the output of splitting/parsing, not perform the parsing itself

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am assuming you need a list of `Tuple<string,string>` as output.

```
var myString = "IND|001;TWN|002;USA|003;LDN|;MYS|005;";
var objects = myString.Split(';')
        .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
        .Select (x => x.Split('|'))
        .Select (x => Tuple.Create(x[0],x[1]))
        .ToList();
```

Result:

```
IND 001 
TWN 002 
USA 003 
LDN
MYS 005
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather then LINQ use `String.Split`.

```
string s = "IND|001;TWN|002;USA|003;LDN|;MYS|005;";

string[] splitData = s.Split(new string[] { "|", ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
string temp= "IND|001;TWN|002;USA|003;LDN|;MYS|005";
IEnumerable<string> returnList = temp.Split(';')
    .Where(g=>!String.IsNullOrEmpty(g))
    .Select(c => c.Substring(0, c.IndexOf('|')) + c.Substring(c.IndexOf('|') + 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myString = "IND|001;TWN|002;USA|003;LDN|;MYS|005;";
            var result = from sp in myString.Split(';')
                         let spr = sp.Split('|')
                         select string.Join(" ", spr);
            string append = string.Empty;
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                append += item + "\n";
            }
            Console.WriteLine(append);
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Comment: Why not just use `string.Join` again instead of `foreach`?